# Using Unclead's Yii2 Multiple input widget. to upload a file

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2

I'm trying to upload a file using Unclead's Yii2 Multiple input widget but if I look at the data being posted I cannot find any file nor can I use `UploadedFile::GetInstance()` or anything similar.

This is the File Input column.

```
[
    'name'  => 'certificates',
    'type'  => fileInput,
    'title' => 'Certificate',
],
```

Comment: Please post full controller method and view file.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your form for enctype

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' (...) >
```

then check dump from `$_FILES`

Answer (score 0):

```
[
'name' => 'saveFile',
'title' => 'File',
'type' => \kartik\file\FileInput::className(),
]
```

Use this way.